# How would I find a UINavigationBar's current UIBarMetrics value?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uibarmetrics

I'm using the `setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:forBarMetrics:` method on UIBarButtonItem's appearance like so:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(12, -1), forBarMetrics: .Default)
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(15, -1), forBarMetrics: .Compact)
```

Then, in a view controller I'd like to use `backButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(for:)` to get the value. I assumed there must be a UIBarMetrics value I could use - perhaps in the navigation bar or a UITraitCollection, but I think I'm missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

you can retrieve the value in a view controller like this

```
if let backButtonItem = navigationItem.backBarButtonItem {
            let offset = backButtonItem.backButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(for: .default)
            print(offset) 
        }
```

we check if the `backBarButtonItem` property of the current view controller's `navigationItem` is not `nil`. If it exists, we retrieve the back button title position adjustment using the `backButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(for:)` method, passing the `.default` bar metrics as the parameter. The method will return the offset adjustment, which you can then use as needed.

Note that if the `backBarButtonItem` is `nil`, it means that the back button is being inherited from the previous view controller or the navigation item does not have a back button set. In this case, you might need to handle it differently depending on your specific requirements